# JSR303: How to check that field already marked as invalid?

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

In my own class-level validator before checking value I want to know are other validators mark it as valid or not?

For instance, before checking that country exists in database I need to ensure that it passes other tests, such as valid length and matches pattern.

How to do this?

---

To clarify what I really wants, this is real-life example:

```
@ValidCredentials(groups = AuthAccountForm.FormChecks.class)
public class AuthAccountForm {

    @NotEmpty(groups = Login1Checks.class)
    @Size.List({
        @Size(min = LOGIN_MIN_LENGTH, message = "{value.too-short}", groups = Login2Checks.class),
        @Size(max = LOGIN_MAX_LENGTH, message = "{value.too-long}", groups = Login2Checks.class)
    })
    @Pattern(regexp = LOGIN_REGEXP, message = "{login.invalid}", groups = Login3Checks.class)
    private String login;

    @NotEmpty(groups = Password1Checks.class)
    @Size(min = PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH, message = "{value.too-short}", groups = Password2Checks.class)
    @Pattern(
        regexp = PASSWORD_REGEXP,
        message = "{password.invalid}",
        groups = Password3Checks.class
    )
    private String password;

    @GroupSequence({ Login1Checks.class, Login2Checks.class, Login3Checks.class })
    public interface LoginChecks { }

    public interface Login1Checks { }
    public interface Login2Checks { }
    public interface Login3Checks { }

    @GroupSequence({ Password1Checks.class, Password2Checks.class, Password3Checks.class })
    public interface PasswordChecks { }

    public interface Password1Checks { }
    public interface Password2Checks { }
    public interface Password3Checks { }

    public interface FormChecks { }

}
```

And in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processInput(
        @Validated({
            LoginChecks.class,
            PasswordChecks.class,
            FormChecks.class
        }) final AuthAccountForm form,
        final BindingResult result) {
```

So, now in `ValidCredentialsValidator` before checks password and login, I need to ensure that them are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Groups and Group sequence. In a Group sequence if at least one constraints fails the constraints of the following groups in the sequence get validated. More information are available [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups).

For example:

```
@GroupSequence({ Person.class, Group1.class, Group2.class })
class Person {
    @Size(min=4, groups=Group1.class)
    @Pattern("[a-z]+", groups=Group1.class)
    @CheckExistence(groups=Group2.class)
    String country;
}
```

In this example if we validate the Default group, constraints belonging to Person will be validated first then the constraints of Group1 and the constraints of Group2. If one constraints of Group1 is failling the Group2 is not validated.

Comment: I'm very sorry that I not posted real code. (See updated question.) I've already use `groups` with `@GroupSequence` and I need to test that checks at other group sequences passes.

Comment: Hi, no problem! I think in your @Validated annotation you have to pass a group sequence which defines an order between LoginChecks.class, PasswordChecks.class and FormChecks.class. Normally with the BV algorithm defined for group sequence ValidCredentialsValidator will only be called if password and login are valid.